Coloring a QGIS Map with an RGB Column, and Creating a Legend that follows the same color
I'm working on a project in QGIS where I need to color a map using RGB values from a specific column in my dataset (RGB). However, I also need to create a legend that shows the units with their actual RGB color. I've run into a problem because using the RGB values directly doesn't allow for categorization, and thus, I can't generate a legend that displays the units. I was hoping there would be an option somewhere within the legend section to select colors based on either the actual color of the shape, or the RGB column itself.
Essentially:

Color the map based on RGB values from a column in my attribute table. (Done)
Create a legend that shows the units with their actual color. (Not done)

I can't seem to find a way to do both simultaneously. Is there a method or workaround in QGIS that allows me to color the map using RGB values and also create a legend showing the units? I know it can be done manually, however due to scalability it is not really a possibility.

This python code creates a legend using a text field called rgb:
from qgis.core import QgsSymbol, QgsRendererCategory, QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer
from qgis.utils import iface
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# Get the field name that contains the RGB values
field_name = 'rgb' 

# Create an empty list to hold the renderer categories
categories = []

# Create a set to hold the RGB values that have been encountered
encountered_rgb_values = set()

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    rgb = feature[field_name]

# If this RGB value has already been encountered, skip it
    if rgb in encountered_rgb_values:
        continue

    # Otherwise, add it to the set of encountered RGB values
    encountered_rgb_values.add(rgb)

    # Split the RGB value into a list of integers
    rgb_values = list(map(int, rgb.split(',')))

    # Create a symbol with the RGB color
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    symbol.setColor(QColor(*rgb_values))

    # Create a category with the symbol and add it to the list
    category = QgsRendererCategory(feature[field_name], symbol, feature[field_name])
    categories.append(category)

# Create a categorized renderer
renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer(field_name, categories)

# Assign the renderer to the layer
layer.setRenderer(renderer)
layer.triggerRepaint()

Setup before running it:

Setup after with console text editor:


Thank you very much, solved my issue! Just had to make a couple edits to fit some requirements I forgot to mention.
